# Logging wrong password for ssh with key

Tags: sshd, openssh

I have already configured  login to ssh with keys and it works fine. The problem is that when I'm connecting to the server with key and included password but I don't see any failed login attempts when I type a wrong password. There are no failed login attempts using key in:

```
/var/log/audit/audit.log
```

or

```
/var/log/secure
```

Other words i can type password to key til i die without any action.
Do you have any ideas how to log to file failed login attemps to ssh using key with password ?

OS is : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

Thank you in advance.

This is log from the server when i have typed many times wrong password:

```
Connection from my_ip port 51115 on server_ip port 22
sshd[3639]: Found matching RSA key: 00:12:23 ...
sshd[3639]: Postponed publickey for some_user from ip_address port 51115 ssh2 [preauth]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you've configured your client key to require a password to open the key before connecting to the server.  It won't be logged by your server because that occurs on the client machine.

Comment: Thanks for answer but is there any other possibility to use keys while connecting to ssh serwer and log failed password on the server ?

Comment: @admfotad You mean to log failed attempts at unlocking the key?

Comment: Yes, when i get any login attempt using key with wrong password i can then block client ip with fail2ban on the server - but i need any logs on the server before. For example this i log from the server when i typed on client side wrong password many times:   Connection from my_ip port 51115 on server_ip port 22
sshd[3639]: Found matching RSA key: 00:12:23 ...
sshd[3639]: Postponed publickey for some_user from ip_address port 51115 ssh2 [preauth]

Comment: By 'wrong password' do you by chance actually mean 'invalid key'?  Because you can't use an ssh key with a wrong password.  The password is to protect the key from unauthorized use.

Comment: Key is valid but i wanted to track on the server when wrong password to  client key is typed  but as i can see from your answer it is only to protect  access to client key not to verify this password on server side. If so i vane no more questions and thanks for explaining. Regards

Comment: @admfotad, yeah, there's no way the server will be informed of this.  You'd need to look for a local event logged on the client machine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the passphrase protecting the SSH key is completely a client-side matter. Consider that even `ssh-keygen` allows you to change the passphrase without a connection to any server (`ssh-keygen -p -f id_rsa`). Of course that requires knowing the old passphrase, but you can (try to) guess it without hinting the server you're doing that.

That said, when connecting to a server, the SSH client offers the server any keys it has *before* asking for a passphrase to decrypt the key. You'll note that if you connect to a host that doesn't accept your key, the passphrase is never asked.

```
$ ssh -v -v somehost
...
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /...
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 407
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp blah
debug1: key_load_private_type: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
Enter passphrase for key '/...':
```

Technically, you could modify the server to detect a client that offers a key, but doesn't follow through with authenticating with it. But that wouldn't help since any attacker could just try to decrypt the keys first before trying to authenticate. Again, this is possible even with the usual utilities: it's what you do when running `ssh-agent`.

If a key is not enough for you, current versions of OpenSSH allow the server to require both a key *and* a password. The [documentation](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthenticationMethods) gives this as an example to require first a key, then a password (using either "password" or "keyboard-interactive" authentication):

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

Comment: Thanks for hint. I tried connecting to server with wrong key and i will try now to block with fail2ban clients with bad keys.

Comment: @admfotad, yeah, of course you can detect connections that didn't authenticate, regardless of if they had a key to try or just closed for some other reason. But like it said, it doesn't help with keys, if the passphrase on the key is weak, the attacker can just bruteforce it on the client-side _before_ even trying to connect to your server.